# Using nmake with wildcarded targets

Tags: makefile, nmake

Using `nmake` I have the following makefile which currently does what I need it to do. `mycmd` (the program being run) will take a `.inp` file and produce a `.out` file. I can make as many `.inp` files as I need to and the makefile doesn't have to change. It will find them all and make all the relevant `.out` files.

```
#####################################################################################
# A SUFFIXES declaration is required in order to later use the rule with target .inp.out
#####################################################################################
.SUFFIXES: .inp

#####################################################################################
# Here, NMAKE will expand *.inp in the prereq list for all, into the list of *.inp
# files in the directory, and then it will start a new NMAKE instance, specifying the
# goals to build all those files.
#####################################################################################
all: *.inp
  $(MAKE) $(**:.inp=.out)

#####################################################################################
# $(*B) represents the current target's base name minus the path and the file extension
#####################################################################################
.inp.out:
  mycmd -i $(*B).inp -o $(*B).out
```

My question is, how do I enhance this makefile further so that I could, for example, run it for a set of `.inp` files, so not `*.inp` but say, `ABC*.inp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple modification to your makefile should work. Add a new `$(pattern)` macro:

```makefile
.SUFFIXES: .inp

pattern = *                         # new macro, set to default value of *

all: $(pattern).inp                 # use the new macro!
  @$(MAKE) -nologo $(**:.inp=.out)

.inp.out:                           # dummy stub for testing
  @echo mycmd -i $(*B).inp -o $(*B).out
  @type NUL > $(*B).out
```

Then in your command line, overwrite `pattern`. For example, `nmake -nologo pattern=ABC*`.

---

**Update:** The command line in your makefile:

```
  $(MAKE) $(**:.inp=.out)
```

will fail with `fatal error U1095: expanded command line` ... `too long` if the string `$**` is too long. On my system, this happens at roughly 32800 characters.

Adding an exclamation mark `!` to the start (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/commands-in-a-makefile?view=msvc-170#-command-modifiers)) doesn't seem to work, probably because there is no simple `$**`. Two workarounds are to use:

```
  !call set a=$** & call nmake %%a:.inp=.out%%
```

or:

```
  !for %a in ($**) do nmake -nologo %~na.out
```

These are both about twice as slow as your original, with a do-nothing `mycmd` stub. (The `for` loop here is not really a loop, because `$**` is just a single item.)

Comment: **Edit:** Maybe mention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering.

Comment: Thank you! and Har har on the second comment :-D

Comment: Thanks for the update. My makefile does not need to handle files that are anywhere near  32K characters so this restriction is not a problem for me (who would make file names that long!?)

Comment: Perhaps the only problem with this (otherwise ingenious) approach is when no `.inp` actually matches the pattern in the source dir _(which can easily happen as soon as the build proc. gets generalized to handle arbitrary source trees and multiple extensions etc.)_, and NMAKE would bail out with "U1073: dunno how to make *.inp". Do you have any magic for that, too? Another level of indirection, perhaps? ;)

Answer (score 0):

A different solution is to keep your original makefile, and use a DOS command such as:

```
for %a in (ABC*.inp) do nmake -nologo %~na.out
```

Here the syntax `%~na` removes the extension from the variable `%a`.

This is slightly slower than just using the makefile, but not by much. For example, with 600 `inp` files, and a `mycmd` stub, on my system this command takes 20 seconds compared to 15 seconds for the makefile.